# Collator isn't printing second UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

When I execute my print function, it only prints one of the pages of information, Second Page is empty. If I print Each User Control one at a time, It works. May I ask How do I get the second usercontrol printing information also.

Single Control (works)

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="{Binding FedNorReportVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <StackPanel>
        <panes:PerformanceReportPage1 x:Name="FedNorReportGrid"></panes:PerformanceReportPage1>            
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Two Controllers(doesn't work)

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="{Binding FedNorReportVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <StackPanel>
        <panes:PerformanceReportPage1 x:Name="FedNorReportGrid"></panes:PerformanceReportPage1>
        <panes:PerformanceReportPage2 x:Name="FedNorReportGrid2"></panes:PerformanceReportPage2>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Print Function:

```
using (var doc = new XpsDocument("C:\\Users/UNKNOWN/Test2.xps", FileAccess.Write))
{
     var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
     var collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();

     collator.BeginBatchWrite();
     collator.Write(FedNorReportGrid);
     collator.Write(FedNorReportGrid2);
     collator.EndBatchWrite();
}

var doc2 = new XpsDocument("C:\\Users/UNKNOWN/Test2.xps", FileAccess.Read);

var seq = doc2.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

var window = new Window();
window.Content = new DocumentViewer {Document = seq};
window.ShowDialog();
```

It's sort of weird. I can make it print two pages of the first "Pane". The second pane won't ever show with anything I try. using

```
collator.Write(FedNorReportGrid);
collator.Write(FedNorReportGrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

How Silly is this.... If I encapsulate each Pane in their own StackPanel, It works....

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <panes:PerformanceReportPage1 x:Name="FedNorReportGrid"></panes:PerformanceReportPage1>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <panes:PerformanceReportPage2 x:Name="FedNorReportGrid2"></panes:PerformanceReportPage2>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```